# Linq to Xml, Filter Element from Query (C#)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm simply trying to query an xml document and iterate over the results minus specific elements. Ideally I would like to achieve this in the query rather than removing it from the collection before or during iteration.

```
<body>
       Stuff I want
  <element>
       Stuff I dont want
  </element>
</body>
```

I tried something along these lines but had no luck....

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("document.xml");
        var results = doc.Descendants("body")
                         .Where(x => x.Name != "element")
```

I'm certainly out of my element using XML, apologies if this has been answered already.

Comment: How defined is your schema? Can your undesired elements appear in multiple places, or are they all immediately under the body?

Comment: A better XML sample would help. Is "Stuff I want" just text or can it be a mix of text and elements?

Comment: The "<body>" just represents a parent element.  It contains text and elements as well as the node I want to filter out.  The schema is well defined, a little too complex to post here. I was just wondering if there was a simple way to filter a given node in the query. Right now I have a simple method removing the element from the collection after the query.

Comment: var element = results.Descendants("element");
element.Remove();

Comment: @Justin - that code's just fine; not sure what you see wrong with it?

Comment: @Alex I havent messed around with XML really, most SQL. I was just wondering if there was some filtering method I was missing out on, in the query but yea, this should work just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin: Please mark it if this answers your question, which seems it does, or state explicitly otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to grab the document, query for the stuff you don't want, and then .Remove() them.  For example, if you're XML looked something like the following:

```
<body>
    Stuff I want
    <element>Stuff I dont want</element>
    <element>Stuff I want</element>
</body>
```

You could do the following code to alter the document with everything except for the  containing "Stuff I don't want":

```
        var doc = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");

        IEnumerable<XElement> nodes =
                                from node in doc.Descendants("element")
                                where node.Value == "Stuff I dont want"
                                select node;

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            nodes.Remove();
        }
```

Which would then yield the following in your doc:

```
<body>
    Stuff I want
    <element>Stuff I want</element>
</body>
```

Comment: Almost tempted to ruin your very nice score (404) with an upvote :), but shouldn't `nodes.Remove()` actually be more along the lines of `nodes.ToList().ForEach(e => e.Remove())` ? (Also, for more nitpicking, I think `nodes` will never be null, just possibly empty)