# How do I retrieve and filter data from XML file Using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, database, linq

I am working with Windows form application. In that I retrieve the data from XML and filter needed data from that. I am using for loop which made our application slow. So I like to go with Linq. I need some tutorial and example to retrieve and filter data from XML using Linq. Another question is that , I retrieve and filter data from database. Its also getting slow. Is it possible to speed up process with the help of linq?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760764/linq-to-xml-filter-element-from-query-c/3761626#3761626 ?  There are tons of good examples on MSDN or if you Bing.  If you have a specific question or example of what you want to do, that could also help to clarify your question a bit to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx
2. http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoXML.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)